Is it possible to create a Windows usergroup that has basic Admin Privileges for a tech support worker to carry out repairs?
I recently rented a dedicated Windows Server 2022 Standard Edition, and whilst trying to fix an issue I was having I accidentally lost network connectivity and was unable to use RDP as my servers IP was unreachable.
My hosting provider technical support team asked for my login credentials to fix the issue, which made me quite uncomfortable. Not because there's anything duplicitous on there, but there's a lot of offline credentials for various paid services I use, a lot of expensive software and license keys (I was in the process of setting the server up at the time), a SQL database with private and confidential user data, and of course all my intellectual property.
Tech support was able to fix the issue and I changed my password as soon as I regained access. But it got me thinking, can I create an account for tech support to use (should they need to) whilst protecting access to my data?
I've researched it quite a bit but with no clear answer. ChatGPT had a lot of suggestions, but ultimately I couldn't create a usergroup that could run, say, CMD with admin privileges, PowerShell with admin privileges or access Windows Registry without prompting for the administrator password. And general consensus online seems to be "why would you need that? Just give admin privileges to admin users".

Just create a separate admin user for them and tell them the credentials, so that you can track who did what and if/when they logged in.
If you don't trust your hosting provider, you have worse problems.
They could boot your server from a live CD and change your admin password, or pull out the disks and read whatever they want, or just really do anything which requires physical access to the server (which they have, and you don't).

This is the approach I've chosen to take. And it's not that I don't trust them as a company, they're reputable, and their support staff have been professional. But just because a hosting provider is trustworthy doesn’t mean all individual members of their tech team are too, or that mistakes can't happen. It seems basic security protocol to limit access where possible, regardless of the circumstances.
And whilst it's true that with physical access they could bypass many controls, that doesn't mean I should hand over more access than is needed when accessing the server with credentials.

In order to fix something, you need admin access; there's no way around that.

I understand, I was just curious if t was possible to setup a user group with limited admin privileges, a sort of "admin-lite" group, but it doesn't seem so. Thanks all the same for your input though.

You could take a different approach and treat the server like cattle, not a pet. Have them wipe the server if you need them to do work and rebuild it yourself from code, not manually.

offline credentials for various paid services I use


Store these in a vault


a lot of expensive software and license keys


The rebuild process and using a vault can solve that


(I was in the process of setting the server up at the time)


Put effort into provisioning and config management so you're not doing this manually


a SQL database with private and confidential user data


Restore from backups. (I hope you're taking backups)


Thank you for the suggestions. All my root credentials are stored in an encrypted cloud vault along with various backups including daily DB and system config backups. But API keys and token bearers I tend to keep out of any webroots ofc, but in plain JSON text, I've used VPS's before, but this was my first bare metal dedicated GPU server. I've been a web developer for over 20 years but server deployment and management isn't a strong suit of mine unfortunately, hence losing all connectivity 4 hours into setting up, then perusing what seems to be an impossible task ha... Thanks again though.
